# How to get current month number from date object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to compare the value of month number field `month=6`coming from my backend to the current month number. if the match is true 'do something' else do 'something else'.

I have tried making use of javascript Date() object and also moment():

```
var date  = new Date();
        var month = date.getMonth()+1;
```

Moment:

```
var month = moment().month("M");
```

This here is the function where the value of the current month is required

```
// get all Item usage on each item by month
        const GroupedByMonth = Object.values(
            data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                if (curr._id.month === month){
                    return (
                        (acc[curr._id.name] = {
                            month: curr._id.month,
                            name: curr._id.name,
                            totalAmountSold:
                                (acc[curr._id.name]?.totalAmountSold || 0) +
                                curr.totalAmountSold,
                        }),
                        acc
                    );
                }
                return acc;
            }, {})
        );

        console.log(GroupedByMonth);
```

Object from backend :

```
{month: 6, name: "Cement", totalAmountSold: -17}
```

expected output should should read :

```
if (curr._id.month(6 coming from backend) === month(6 coming from date object){
in the case of true, the rest of the functions is performed

Non of the method i tried worked as expected. I need help in solving this problem
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. What happens? What would you expect instead? Do you know that `Date#getMonth` returns a zero-indexed number of the month (i.e. January is 0)?

Comment: What is the object that you get from backend that contains the month?

Comment: date.getMonth() returns number. Are you sure that `curr._id.month` has type Number?

Comment: {month: 6, name: "Cement", totalAmountSold: -17}

Comment: `.getMonth()` and momentjs `.month()` both return a zero-indexed month (check their docus). And `moment().month("M")` returns a momentjs object.

Comment: `new Date().getMonth()` does *not* return `6` as you seem to assume, but `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function isDateMatched (monthNo) {
  return new Date().getMonth() === monthNo;
}

console.log('5th month ', isDateMatched(5))
console.log('4th month ', isDateMatched(4))
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

`Date.getMonth()` returns current month no.

You can simply pass the monthNo you get from backend & pass it to `isDateMatched` function, it will return a Boolean i.e, true/false

Based on this result you can do your work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you mean by

> Non of the method i tried worked as expected.

What have you tried so far? And what are the results?

That aside you can try something like this:

```
var today = new Date(); //Thu Jun 18 2020 10:17:04 GMT-0300
var month = ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

//Expected output of month: '06'
```

Make sure that what you are trying to compare matches in value and type, since you are using `===`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had to changed  === to == and it worked fine